# PySpark - How to perform operations on specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, bigdata

I'm trying to perform round function on `df.summary()` dataframe, excluding the summary column. So far I've tried using using `select()` and a comprehension list e.g.

##### Code

```
df2 = df.select(*[round(column, 2).alias(column) for column in df.columns])
```

##### Output

This is the output of `df2` the categorical values get converted into `NULL`.

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Summary | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| NULL    | 0     | 0.1   | 0.2   | 0.3   |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| NULL    | 1     | 1.1   | 1.2   | 1.3   |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| NULL    | 2     | 2.1   | 2.2   | 2.3   |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

##### Desired Output

I want only `columns[1:]` to be rounded.

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Summary | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| min     | 0     | 0.1   | 0.2   | 0.3   |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| max     | 1     | 1.1   | 1.2   | 1.3   |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| stddev  | 2     | 2.1   | 2.2   | 2.3   |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I've also tried slicing `df.columns[1:]`, but then it doesn't select the summary column.

```
df2 = df.select(*[round(column, 2).alias(column) for column in df.columns[1:])
```

##### Output

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col 4 | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0.3   | 0     | 0.1   | 0.2   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1.3   | 1     | 1.1   | 1.2   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2.3   | 2     | 2.1   | 2.2   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the first column from the rounding operation, you can modify your code to selectively apply the rounding operation only to the desired columns. You may try the following:

```
columns_to_round = df.columns[1:]
rounded_df = df.selectExpr("Summary", *[f"round({column}, 2) as {column}" for column in columns_to_round])
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: I tried it in my local and it worked. Where exactly did you get stuck? Try adding `df = df.summary` before the code chunk

Comment: This is column order dependent.

Comment: @Kashyap Yes, it is. Since the DataFrame.summary already returns a DF whose first column 'Summary' contains descriptive info (count, mean, stddev etc.), this does not make any difference in the results

Comment: True in this case. In general, it seems a bad idea from maintenance pov to be order dependent, when writing code that's not order dependent is not much extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(schema='Summary: string,col1: int,col2: float,col3: float,col4: float',
... data=[('min',0,0.1356262,0.2356262,0.3356262,),
... ('max',1,1.1356262,1.2356262,1.3356262,),])
>>> df.show()
+-------+----+---------+---------+---------+
|Summary|col1|     col2|     col3|     col4|
+-------+----+---------+---------+---------+
|    min|   0|0.1356262|0.2356262|0.3356262|
|    max|   1|1.1356262|1.2356262|1.3356262|
+-------+----+---------+---------+---------+

>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df.select(
...   'Summary',
...    *[F.round(c, 2).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c.lower() != 'summary']
... ).show()
+-------+----+----+----+----+
|Summary|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+-------+----+----+----+----+
|    min|   0|0.14|0.24|0.34|
|    max|   1|1.14|1.24|1.34|
+-------+----+----+----+----+

>>>
```